# Could not find default credentials

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I'm playing with Google container engine on gcloud. So after successfully finished `gloud init` I followed instructions and did:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-1 --zone europe-west1-c --project whatever
```

And then:

```
kubectl proxy
```

But I got the following error message:

```
error: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

I do see stuff in `~/.kube/config` file so I'm not sure what went wrong. I have `minikube` also installed on the machine but I don't think that's a problem.

Answer (score 208):

Use

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

to login for application default creadentials ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)). The behavior for application default credentials has [changed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes#12800_20160928) in `gcloud` since version 128.

Note that changing credentials via `gcloud auth login` or `gcloud init` or `gcloud config set account MY_ACCOUNT` will NOT affect application default credentials, they managed separately from gcloud credentials.

Comment: works for me when I keep getting creating client: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information